# I want to add a $ after a ? in all the lines on vi. How can I do this with Regex?

Tags: regex, vim

I want to add a $ after any ? in all the lines on vi. How can I do this with Regex?

Answer (score 6):

replace all instances of `\?` with `\?\$`

```
s/\?/\?\$/g
```

Comment: All the lines = `:%s/\?/\?\$/g` instead, I would suggest.

Answer (score 1):

replace all ? with ?$

```
:%s/?/?$/g
```